# Magnetic flux density in a point

Tags: power, transmission-line, magnetic-flux

This is a single phase copper line in the next configuration
[image]
So its asked to find the magnetic flux density  internal and external due \$I_{A}\$ and \$I_{B}\$ affecting the A cable and measured in the point \$P\$.
\$I_{A}=500\,A\$ and \$I_{B}=-I_{A}\$, the outside diameter in inches is \$0.710\$.
Solving it this way
\$r=\frac{0.710\,in}{2}=0.009017\,m\$

\$d_{AP}=150+2=152\,m\$

\$I_{A}\$ Effect

\$\phi_{extA}=\frac{\mu_{0}I_{A}}{2\pi}ln\frac{d_{AP}}{r}=\frac{4\pi\times10^{-7}(500)}{2\pi}ln\frac{152}{0.009017}=97.32524115\times10^{-6}\,Wb\$

\$\phi_{intA=}\frac{\mu_{0}I_{A}}{8\pi}=\frac{4\pi\times10^{-7}(500)}{8\pi}=25\times10^{-6}\,Wb\$

\$I_{B}\$  effect

\$\phi_{BA_{p}}=\frac{\mu_{0}I_{B}}{2\pi}ln\frac{d_{AP}}{r}=\frac{4\pi\times10^{-7}(-500)}{2\pi}ln\frac{150}{2}=-4.31749\times10^{-4}\,Wb\$

But whats puzzle me its the value of the flux measured in the point \$P\$, since I couldnt calculated it was provided as
\$\phi_{AP}=5.663\times10^{-4}\,Wb\$
but whats the right distance to write in the numerator?
I understand from the \$A\$ cable to the \$P\$ point there is 152 meters the same radius, so it would render the equation to zero flux, but I dont think its right since the lines of the field extend to the infinity so there must be some flux in the point \$P\$ due the current in  \$A\$.
So finally, whats the righ distance to take?
\$\phi_{AP}=\frac{4\pi\times10^{-7}(-500)}{2\pi}ln\frac{?}{152}=5.663\times10^{-4}\,Wb\$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks to me like you are calculating flux density: -

[image]

Picture from [here](https://www.coolmagnetman.com/magfund02.htm).

So, use superposition.

Note also that the external diameters of A and B are irrelevant to solve this.

Comment: But the results does not add to the value given (97+25)+-4=-3.094x10-4

Comment: I get 8.78 nano teslas at point P